# How to remove horizontal padding from TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components, material-components-android

After migrating to newest version of Material Components (`1.1.0-alpha09`), I've noticed that `TextInputLayout` has some padding horizontal padding. My goal is to achieve the old style of text fields, where there is no background or outline box. So I extended one of the styles, i.e. `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox` and set background color to transparent.

```
<style name="Widget.MyApp.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Now the problem is that this input field looks weird in my app with such horizontal padding (which was necessary for filled or outline box).

[image: Screenshot]

So my question is, how can I remove this padding?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
       ....
       android:hint="Hint text"       
       style="@style/My.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense" >
```

Then you can define (it requires the version 1.1.0) a custom style using the `materialThemeOverlay` attribute:

```
  <style name="My.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/MyThemeOverlayFilledDense</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyThemeOverlayFilledDense">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyTextInputEditText_filledBox_dense
    </item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyTextInputEditText_filledBox_dense" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox.Dense">
    <item name="android:paddingStart" ns2:ignore="NewApi">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd" ns2:ignore="NewApi">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">4dp</item>
  </style>
```

Here the results (with a default style and the custom style):

[image][image]

Comment: It works, thank you. Can you explain why setting padding to the EditText doesn't work but setting it in theme works?

Comment: @Nominalista some attributes of the EditText are overridden in the TextInputLayout implementation.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Could you explain what the ns2:ignore="NewApi" means/does? Also I am curious, how did you find that? Thanks!

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf the same meaning of @SuppressLint("NewApi"). Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#configuring-lint-checking-in-xml) and you can find it easily in the android styles.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti can you tell me if it is possible to increase the hint text padding left such that the hint text is a little to the right of the edittext value? If yes, how can we achieve that? Here is a link to my question for the same- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67502927/how-to-give-extra-left-padding-to-floating-label-in-textinputlayout-android

Comment: @PriyaSindkar There isn't an attribute for that.

Comment: Then the error will be started from the beginning of the editview; a few pixels after the place TextInputLayout(the green area) has been drawn.