# TextInputEditText padding not working inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I have  TextInputEditText inside TextInputLayout on a ConstraintLayout.

I want to set a **paddingLeft** to the edittext, but it is not working. If I change to paddingStart it is working just fine, but I need paddingLeft:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/phoneNumberHolder"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/inputPhoneNumber"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        style="@style/EditText.OutlinedBox"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                        app:hintEnabled="false"
                        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/colorBrand">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:paddingLeft="90dp"
                            android:hint="@string/edit_user_profile_phone"
                            android:layout_gravity="start"
                            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                            android:inputType="phone" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And EditText.OutlinedBox  is :

```
   <style name="EditText.OutlinedBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        <item name="android:minHeight">56dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunito_regular</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorTextSecondary</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/colorBrand</item>
        <item name="hintEnabled">true</item>
    </style>
```

Is there any trick to do that? it seems the problem is from `Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox`

Comment: isn't paddingLeft & paddingStart same (if layout directions not considered)?

Comment: What is minimum Android API level in your project?

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57749585/how-to-remove-horizontal-padding-from-textinputlayout/57751984#57751984)

Comment: - minimum API is 26 and I am using com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08

- are the same, but my app supports rtl, so i want paddingLeft for that specific EditText

Comment: Minimum API is 26 and I am using com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha08. Left and Start would be the same, but my app supports rtl, so i want paddingLeft for that specific EditText.

Comment: @ghita the question linked works with `android:paddingStart` and `android:paddingLeft` if you want.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti thanks, I have setted the padding programmatically and it worked fine