# How to give extra left padding to floating label in TextInputLayout android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

My requirement is that I need to display the floating label on an Outlined TextInput Box a little to the right of the underlying EditText text value

Something like this-

[image]

See how the label Notes is a little to the right of Enter/View Notes. I tried to use `hintTextAppearance` attribute in the styles with `paddingStart` but the padding is just ignored.

Is there a way to customize the label's margin/padding to set the label a little towards right?